# Clearing std::map under a lock vs moving to a temp object

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++14, mutex, stdmap

I am using a std::map and have large number of elements in it. If I need to clear the map, I can just call clear() on it. It can take some time to clear and especially if done under a lock in a multi-threaded environment, it can block other calls. To avoid calling clear(), I tried this:

```
std::mutex m;
std::map<int, int> my_map; // the map which I want to clear

void func()
{
    std::map<int, int> temp_map;
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(m);
        temp_map = std::move(my_map);
    }
}
```

This will move my_map to temp_map under the lock which will empty it out. And then once the func ends, the temp_map will be destroyed.

Is this a better way to do this to prevent taking the lock for a long time? Are there any performance hits?

Comment: This is a good idea but I would finish with a call to `my_map.clear()` before releasing the lock since IIRC a moved-from standard container is put in an "indeterminate but valid" state -- so the only safe methods to call are those with no preconditions, and `clear()` has no preconditions and will ensure that the state of the map is determinate.

Comment: Or use `map::swap` member function to swap the full and empty maps.

Comment: @RichardCritten That's probably a better idea anyway.

Comment: @RichardCritten Or use [`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/swap2) since it has a specialization for `std::map`.

Comment: I can use std::swap but the complexity will be linear here. Wouldn't be it better to clear() it in that case?

Comment: @K.Wadhwa Both `std::map::swap` and `std::swap` have constant complexity.

Comment: @Blastfurnace thanks for pointing that out. But is there any benefit of using std::swap over std::move()?

Comment: @K.Wadhwa Using `std::swap` means the work done under the lock is O(1) and `my_map` will be left in an empty and valid state when the mutex is unlocked.

Comment: @Blastfurnace thanks for explanation. That helps!

Comment: Also move is only required to be linear, source:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator%3D

Comment: @RichardCritten: No, `move` has 0 complexity, is just a cast to `map&&`. What you cite as linear complexity is `operator=(map&&)`, but it is linear in the size of destination map that in the OP is just created and so is constant (0). The move constructor `map(map&&)` has the expected constant complexity, (unless you play weird with allocators, of course).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend using `swap` instead of `move`. A moved object is not guaranteed to be actually empty <s>or even usable</s>. But with `swap` and a freshly created object you are sure of the results:

```
void func()
{
    std::map<int, int> temp_map;
    using std::swap;
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(m);
        swap(my_map, temp_map);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @rodrigo. This helps!

Comment: @K.Wadhwa: YW. A easy way to see this is consider `swap` as a double `move`: you move the old map out and the new map in.

Comment: yes, but move takes linear time whereas swap is constant.

Comment: @K.Wadhwa: You may be referring to the link in the question comments... I think that is wrong (I replied above). TL;DR; `a = move(b)` is linear on the size of `a` that in your case is the empty map.

Comment: So the only concern for using std::move is the one you provided in the answer I suppose.

Comment: *"A moved object is not guaranteed to be actually empty or even usable."* The standard does not agree with you here. [lib.types.movedfrom]: *"Objects of types defined in the C++ standard library may be moved from (12.8). Move operations may be explicitly specified or implicitly generated. Unless otherwise specified, such moved-from objects shall be placed in a **valid but unspecified state**."* (Emphasis mine.) So `my_map.clear();` would be sufficient to return the moved-from map to a known (and empty) state. But +1 still because swapping is cleaner anyway.

Comment: @cdhowie: You are right. I recall reading that a moved object was only fit for destruction... maybe in an old draft? Anyway, corrected.

Comment: `std::map<int,int>{}.swap(my_map);` even shorter. Don't think, that logically there is a place for "moved from" `std::map` to be rather then just empty.

Comment: @Orient: The whole point of this function is to have the map be cleared outside of the mutex protection. For that you might as well do `my_map.clear()`. About the emptiness, it may well happen if you play funny with custom allocators.